# How to retrieve multiple SQL result set using pymssql/python

Tags: java, python, sql, pymssql

A stored procedure that I am suppose to call returns multiple return result sets instead of the usual 1 result set table. I need to execute that stored procedure and retrieve it's results via python using pymssql.

In Java, this is achievable by extending `org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure`, supplying multiple  `SqlReturnResultSet` and calling the .execute `.execute(params)` returning a `Map<String, Object>` where you can access each returned result set via the `String` key initially supplied in `SqlReturnResultSet`:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlReturnResultSet;
import org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure
{
    public GetMultiple()
    {
        final SqlParameter[] sqlResultParameters = new SqlParameter[] {
                new SqlReturnResultSet("returnResultSet1", new RowMapper()),
                new SqlReturnResultSet("returnResultSet2", new RowMapper())
        };

        declareParameter(sqlResultParameters)

        final Map<String, Object> spResult = super.execute();

        spResult.getOrDefault("returnResultSet1", Collections.emptyList())
        spResult.getOrDefault("returnResultSet2", Collections.emptyList())
    }
}
```

How do I accomplish this in Python?

Answer (score 5):

Python won't map your result sets automatically, instead it will create buffered cursors, but you can iterate through them with `cursor.nextset()`, e.g.:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host="host", user="user", password="pass", db="schema")  # etc.

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.callproc("procedure_name", ("foo", "bar"))  # pass procedure parameters as a tuple
    while True:  # loop while there are result sets
        if cursor.rowcount:  # make sure there are actually results in the current set
            result_set = cursor.fetchall()  # or cursor.fetchone() / cursor.fetchmany()
            # do whatever you want with the result_set, store it in a dict if you want
        # after done processing the current result set, move on to the next
        if not cursor.nextset():  # switch to the next result set, if available...
            break  # exit the loop if not
```